# Plot multiple polygons from factor in same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that I would like to plot like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsOn6.jpg).

Each polygon is comprised of the area between two lines, where the line oordinates (`yVal`) are grouped by a factor in the data frame, either of `type="A"|type="B"`. There is one polygon for each value of `Fac1`. Is there a simple way of doing this in `ggplot`? I found [this example for plotting a single polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387202/fill-the-region-between-two-lines-with-ggplot2-in-r), but I'm hoping that there is a way I can do it by a factor.

A workable data frame is given below:

```
Fac1 <- rep(c(50,95,99),times=6)
xVal <- c(rep(1,times=6),rep(2,times=6),rep(3,times=6))
yVal <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.243,0,0,0.313,0.239,0.513,0.894,0.292,0.708,1.625)
type <- rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),times=3)
df.plot <- as.data.frame(cbind(Fac1,xVal,yVal,type))
```

This gives the data frame:

```
   Fac1  xVal  yVal type
1    50     1     0    A
2    95     1     0    A
3    99     1     0    A
4    50     1     0    B
5    95     1     0    B
6    99     1     0    B
7    50     2     0    A
8    95     2     0    A
9    99     2 0.243    A
10   50     2     0    B
11   95     2     0    B
12   99     2 0.313    B
13   50     3 0.239    A
14   95     3 0.513    A
15   99     3 0.894    A
16   50     3 0.292    B
17   95     3 0.708    B
18   99     3 1.625    B
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what your `type` variable means for the plot, but I think this works:

```
df.plot$Fac1 <- factor(df.plot$Fac1)

ggplot(df.plot, aes(x = xVal, y = yVal, group = Fac1, fill = Fac1)) +
    geom_polygon(alpha = 0.5)
```

The above gives, as you ask for, "one polygon for each value of Fac1". Whatever you specify as `aes(group)` will identify unique polygons.

Maybe both `Fac1` and `type` identify polygons? If so, try this:

```
df.plot$id <- interaction(df.plot$Fac1, df.plot$type)

ggplot(df.plot, aes(x = xVal, y = yVal, group = id, fill = Fac1, color = type)) +
    geom_polygon(alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "firebrick2")) +
    scale_fill_brewer()
```

#### Edit

Ah, I should have noticed your description of "area between two lines". For that, you want `geom_ribbon` not `geom_polygon`, and we'll do a little data transformation (if you added the `id` column from my second guess, get rid of it before running `dcast`):

```
library(reshape2)
wide.df <- dcast(df.plot, Fac1 + xVal ~ type, value.var = "yVal")
ggplot(wide.df, aes(x = xVal, ymin = A, ymax = B, group = Fac1, fill = Fac1)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost does it. The `yVal` variable is one of two paired measurements at different levels for the same `xVal`. The `type` variable is a stand-in that shows which of the paired measurements it belongs to, so there are two lines for `Fac1`.

This seems to work most of the time, but as you can see in [this plot](http://imgur.com/Bqjob1I), the blue polygon should fill down to the black line I added.

Comment: Perfect! So simple, you saved me a ton time. Thanks!